# Function call stack: train_function error while training Bidirectional LSTM

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, lstm

I am a beginner in Machine Learning and  I have been trying to develop a LSTM Neural Network using Sequential Model. The following is my model where I am getting this error:

```
    [[{{node sequential/bidirectional/forward_lstm/while/body/_1/sequential/bidirectional/forward_lstm/while/lstm_cell_1/MatMul}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
[Op:__inference_train_function_3646]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

What is causing this error? I looked up and tried some solutions myself, doesn't seem to work
Model:

```
import keras
import pickle
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



X = []
for i in range(0, 30):
    print(i)
    pickle_in = open("X_1min_" + str(i) + ".pickle", "rb")
    if i == 0:
        X = numpy.array(pickle.load(pickle_in))
    else:
        X = (numpy.append(X, numpy.array(pickle.load(pickle_in)), 0))
    pickle_in.close()
X = numpy.array(X)
print(X)

P = []
for i in range(0, 30):
    print(i)
    pickle_in = open("P_1min_" + str(i) + ".pickle", "rb")
    P.extend(pickle.load(pickle_in))
    pickle_in.close()
P = numpy.array(P)
print(P)

# To get target Y
N_future = 60


def obtain_Y(price, price_low, price_high):
    print("Getting Y")
    Y = []
    for i in range(len(price) - N_future - 1):
        temp = numpy.max(price_high[i:i + N_future])
        Y.append(temp)
    Y = numpy.array(Y)

    print("done")
    return Y

X = X[:-N_future - 1]

COINS = 0
print("COINS: " + str(COINS))
Y = obtain_Y(P[:, COINS * 3], P[:, COINS * 3 + 1], P[:, COINS * 3 + 2])
pickle.dump(Y, open("Y_1min" + str(COINS) + ".sav", 'wb'))

X = X[N_future:]
Y = Y[N_future:]

### Spliting to training and testing dataset
NUM_POINTS = 43200 * 4  # 43200*3 means data from latest 3 months are used for test
X_train = numpy.array(X[:-NUM_POINTS])
Y_train = numpy.array(Y[:-NUM_POINTS])
X_test = numpy.array(X[-NUM_POINTS:])
Y_test = numpy.array(Y[-NUM_POINTS:])

remove_data = len(X_train) % 5000
X_train = X_train[remove_data:]
Y_train = Y_train[remove_data:]



X_train = shuffle(X_train)
Y_train = shuffle(Y_train)


### Scaling input X_train and X_Test, and target Y_train (not Y_test)
scalerX = MinMaxScaler()
scalerX.fit(X_train)
pickle.dump(scalerX, open("scalerX_1min" + str(COINS) + ".sav", 'wb'))
X_train = scalerX.transform(X_train)
X_test = scalerX.transform(X_test)

scalerY = MinMaxScaler()
scalerY.fit(numpy.reshape(Y_train, (-1, 1)))
pickle.dump(scalerY, open("scalerY_1min" + str(COINS) + ".sav", 'wb'))
Y_train_scaled = scalerY.transform(numpy.reshape(Y_train, (-1, 1)))




reshapedX = X_train.reshape(224, 5000, 16)
X_train = reshapedX

reshapedY = Y_train_scaled.reshape(224, 5000, 1)
Y_train_scaled = reshapedY


model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(200, input_shape=(5000,16 ,10 ), activation='relu', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, 0.0001)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train_scaled, epochs=150, batch_size=5000, verbose=1)





predictions = model.predict(X_train)
predictions = scalerY.inverse_transform(predictions)
MeanAE_train = numpy.mean(abs(numpy.reshape(predictions, (1, -1)) - Y_train))
print("MeanAE_train: " + str(MeanAE_train))
MaxAE_train = numpy.mean(abs(numpy.reshape(predictions, (1, -1)) - Y_train))
print("MaxAE_train: " + str(MaxAE_train))
accuracy_train = []
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    accuracy_train.append(abs(predictions[i] - Y_train[i]) / Y_train[i] * 100)
accuracy_train = numpy.array(accuracy_train)
print("Training accuracy: " + str(100 - numpy.mean(accuracy_train)) + "%")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(Y_train)
plt.plot(predictions)
plt.title('Training')
plt.legend(['Ideal', 'Prediction'])

print("\n")
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = scalerY.inverse_transform(predictions)
MeanAE_test = numpy.mean(abs(numpy.reshape(predictions, (1, -1)) - Y_test))
print("MeanAE_test: " + str(MeanAE_test))
MaxAE_test = numpy.max(abs(numpy.reshape(predictions, (1, -1)) - Y_test))
print("MaxAE_test: " + str(MaxAE_test))
accuracy_test = []
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    accuracy_test.append(abs(predictions[i] - Y_test[i]) / Y_test[i] * 100)
accuracy_test = numpy.array(accuracy_test)
print("Testing accuracy: " + str(100 - numpy.mean(accuracy_test)) + "%")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(Y_test)
plt.plot(predictions)
plt.title('Training')
plt.legend(['Ideal', 'Prediction'])
plt.show(block=True)
```